# Is there an HTML5 support in Java SWT?

Tags: java, html, swt

Is there a possibility to render HTML5 content on the client side using regular JAVA application? I mean is there an HTML5 support in JAVA?

Comment: you can use anything on the front end Java does not stops you from that....

Comment: Assuming that the answer by sanbhat is not the answer you are looking for, try this:  Java does not inherently support HTML (except by browser widgets).  Your's is a common problem, which means there may already be a free library that solves your problem.  Try using google to search "java html 5 support" or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that you are talking about [SWT Browser widget](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-browser-widget/browser.html). As per the linked article,

> The SWT Browser widget embeds a platform's popular HTML rendering
>   engine: Internet Explorer on a Microsoft® Windows® platform, Mozilla
>   on Linux®, Safari on the Mac.

So it depends on whether IE, Mozilla, Safari support HTML5

Comment: If these browsers support HTML5 or at least a subset of HTML5 depends on which version of the browsers is embedded.